# Dynamic property in c# depending on enum value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to create make a property in a class dyanmic depending on the enum property of the class.

e.g i have a class of meeting and it has an enum of locations, if a location is picked the location details should be different for example if Inperson is picked then the location details should be a class of type Address else if the location of zoom is picked the details should just be a string with the url

```
public enum Meeting_Location
{
InPerson,
Zoom,
GoogleMeet
}

public class Meeting
{
public string Name;
public Meeting_Location Location;
public ... Location_Details; --> this is dynamic depending on the enum that is selected
}

public class Address
{
public string postcode;
public string country;
public string StreetName;
....

}
```

Comment: Base location type with derived specific classes?

Comment: So what if when `Zoom` is selected in that case what would be expected `Location_Details` and in case of `GoogleMeet` what would be the `Location_Details`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I don't suggest you to use an enum to tell the type of the meeting. Instead, you should use polymorphism. To make the class itself being the type of meeting.

```cs
public abstract class Meeting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class InPersonMeeting : Meeting
{
    public Address Location { get; set; }
}

public class ZoomMeeting : Meeting
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but how do i configure it in entity framework cause i only want to have one table for all the types of meeting